# Check if PHP script is running, and if not run it

Tags: php, background-process

I am running a PHP file using

```
nohup php server.php &
```

This listens for a particular port and does actions according to the input.

The problem is that sometimes the script stops. I cannot use a cron job to fix this, because my server is listening to a port all the time and also is creating child processes.

Is there a way to check if `server.php` is running and (if not) start it?

Comment: Make server.php listen on an UNIX domain socket, and answer with its status when queried.  Poll it from `cron` every few minutes, and restart it if it doesn't answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the process using `ps`, but one drawback is that if you have multiple instances of this process running or if the script is hung up then this method can be less than conclusive.

I prefer to actually check if the server is listening on the port. Here are a couple of ways to do this. If your server is listening on port 2000 for example consider the following.

### Using `lsof`

```
lsof -i :2000; echo $?;
```

`lsof` is checking for open file descriptors and should show whether or not a program is listening or actively communicating on this port. This will echo either a `0` if the server is accepting connections on port 2000 or a `1` if it is not.

### Using `nc`

```
nc -z -w1 192.168.1.12 2000 &> /dev/null; echo $?;
```

This is my preferred method for checking on a socket server. Here `nc` is using the `-z` flag for zero I/O mode to quickly scan the port. You can use your IP address here and the correct port. If the server is accepting connections then life is good.

Again here return values will be either a `0` for good or a `1` for not good. We are discarding any output here because we are wanting just a quick boolean check. This method returns very fast if the network address is reachable. Run from the server itself you will not see hardly any latency as it is trying to talk to itself.

### Automating

To run these tests via cron, create a bash script and execute one or both of these commands and run through a series of logical checks. If they fail restart your script and recheck. I have been using these methods for several years now and have had very good results of practical uptime.

Comment: i am trying to automate the same but when i use nohup inside the bash its running and exiting at the same time ( executing the bash from root folder )

Comment: Please check this link http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213283/nohup-not-working-when-called-from-root-folder

Answer (score 1):

Little bit late to the party...

By using the restartd daemon you are able to run programs and bash scripts. Restartd will check every 20 seconds (configurable) if the programs in its list are running.

See the man page [here](http://man.cx/restartd(8))

Answer (score 0):

not sure this solve your XY problem

```
if ps -C php -o args h | grep -q server.php
then true ## php server.php running
else php server.php ## not running
fi
```

## ps

- `-C php` will seach for php instance,
- `-o args` will display full command line,
- `h` without header

## grep

- `-q` be quiet

---

This will check whether `php server.php` is running, if programm is stop process will be here and will no relaunch.

Real solution include polling server.php using whatever connection, expecting a know answer without timeout. if fail relaunch.