# nohup is not working when called from root folder

Tags: php, background-process, nohup

When I execute the `nohup` command from the same folder it's working fine (server.php is used to listen to a port 7070)

```
root@servername:/var/www/html/admin# nohup php server.php &
[4] 2803
root@servername:/var/www/html/admin# nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’

root@servername:/var/www/html/admin# lsof -i :7070; echo $?
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
php     2803 root    3u  IPv4  21955      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.12:7070 (LISTEN)
0
root@servername:/var/www/html/admin# kill 2803
```

Now when i do the same command from the *root* it is auto exiting

```
root@servername:/var/www/html/admin# cd /
root@servername:/# nohup php /var/www/html/admin/server.php &
[4] 2807
root@servername:/# nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’

[4]   Exit 255                nohup php /var/www/html/admin/server.php
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `nohup.out` saying?

Comment: What are the contents of `server.php`? Maybe the script uses relative paths and therefore fails...

Comment: i got a nohup.out message  failed to open stream: ,,, and i changed it to absolute

Comment: Thanks Chaos ,,, my mistake ,,, inside one more relative path was there ... thanks for pointing ,,, error_reporting was 0 for that file thats y no output in nohup thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue. Your script may have called other scripts, and you didn't use the absolute path to call other scripts. To fix this issue, make sure all the scripts have absolute paths when calling another scripts